# bindToController not working with underscore in name

Tags: angularjs

I need some help with what i think must be a silly error. This is the code I am using but this.area_id and this.location_id are coming through as undefined. What am I missing?

HTML

```
<location-search area_id="1" location_id='376'>
</location-search>
```

JS

```
class locSearchController {
    constructor(Search, $state) {
        this.$state = $state;
        this.Search = Search;
        debugger;
        this.params = {};
        this.params.area_id = this.area_id;
        this.params.location_id = this.location_id;
    }
}
var locationSearch = function() {
    return {
        bindToController: {
            area_id: '@',
            location_id: '@'
        },
        scope: {
        },
        controller: locSearchController,
        templateUrl: 'frontpage/location.dir.html',
        controllerAs: 'vm'
    }
}
angular.module('app')
.directive('locationSearch', locationSearch);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular normalizes the directive attribute names to camelCased version. Try:

```
bindToController: {
    areaId: '@',
    locationId: '@'
}
```

And, access in your controller as:

```
this.areaId;
this.locationId;
```